# Congratulations on being mentioned on Futurama's Facebook page!

Tags: discussion

[image]
https://www.facebook.com/Futurama/posts/313500278739993

I was browsing Facebook this evening and noticed a link to the SciFi Stack Exchange on Futurama's newsfeed! Congratulations - this should bring a good bit of traffic.

Comment: THis is causing issues: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1977/holy-monkeys-batman-that-is-a-lot-of-posts?lq=1 LOL

Comment: @TheDoctor: Wasn't me! ;)