# Holy monkeys Batman! That is A LOT of posts!

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I think due to what happened here: [Congratulations on being mentioned on Futurama's Facebook page!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1971/3383), or most probably here: https://www.facebook.com/Futurama/posts/320014191418612

We are getting **MANY** [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) posts within the past few minutes.

How can these be moderated fluently?

Many of them seem very ***VERY*** spammy.

(*Yay to my flagging score going up and up and uppp!*)

Comment: Your Facebook link is three days old. This is the one that's happening right now: http://www.facebook.com/Futurama/posts/320014191418612. They have linked to us previously, but "Hey! Win stuff" is just stronger :)

Comment: @balpha haha it seems that might be it! (I can't go on facebook in my office so I am going of what other say)

Comment: Is this something someone in the s.e.  did intentionally drive traffic here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This reminds me of how the hostile atheists flooded the Christianity.se site asking the dumbest questions. (Don't get me wrong, they weren't all dumb. The ones I'm talking about were there with the express purpose of being rude, disruptive, and disrespectful. Some very smart atheists frequent the site and keep it interesting in a good way.)

I don't think the Futurama posters are *intentionally* hostile, but the questions are dragging the site down - duplicates, easily answered by a single link, just plain dumb. ([How do you make ice cream soup?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19477/how-does-fry-make-ice-cream-soup) really?) It makes it hard to find the good questions, which dumbs down an otherwise fun S.E. site.

The mods, and other contributors that wanted to see the Christianity site succeed got it under control over several months by enlisting the aid of the community, endless chats about the best way to enforce the standards, and setting the tone for what's acceptable by setting up meta posts about undesired behavior, and closing questions aggressively, with links back to the Meta posts explaining "if you want to know how to get your post reopened, click here".

It took a while to find the right balance between over-aggressiveness and allowing interesting questions that "seekers" would really ask, but they did find a good balance eventually.

The key was in enlisting all the "regulars" in playing an active role in educating newbies to the standards, and enforcing them with down-votes and close votes.  I think that the long discussions, which led to the various Meta guidelines were the key in improving the tine and quality of the questions in the face of openly hostile posters.

The Futurama people may not be openly hostile, but the quality of the questions is equally low in many cases.  I think there are parallels here, and the danger of the site being drawn down to a truly awful, un-enjoyable level is here as well.

Hopefully, it won't be necessary to go that far. I'm hoping the ones asking the inane questions will get bored and move on, while the ones asking good questions stick around.

Comment: downvotes on questions are free

Comment: @Ben Are downvotes an effective tool against a _massive_ influx of low-quality questions, though? I think this Futurama marketing campaign backfired :( (disclaimer: I tend to disagree with "contests" and marketing campaigns of any kind)

Comment: @AndresF - My original post mentioned that I was downvoting and worried about losing what little rep I have. I edited my question. His comment made more sense before I edited and changed the context.

Comment: It looks like this isn't a lasting concern, [we are already old news to the Futurama crowd](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/please-have-introductory-material-on-the-answerama-front-page/1983#1983). The few who will stick around are likely to be the ones who understand what SE is about.

Comment: “What little rep”? A downvote on a question is free, a downvote on an answer costs 1/10 of what you receive for an upvote on an answer. At ~4000rep, you could downvote 40 posts a day and not notice it.

Answer (score 11):

We mods are doing what we can, anyone with the rep to do so should help out by going through flags, voting to close, up and down voting, and adding comments guiding the *many* new users to the FAQ.

Looks like half an hour ago the Futurama Facebook page linked to Answerama.

Comment: That is what I linked to in my OP ^_^

Comment: Keen --- That message that was put up is **too small** and hard to read...

Comment: @TheDoctor We just pushed a fix to make that message a bit more prominent. Should appear Soon(TM).